# Firebase query that returns objects

Tags: javascript, json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have the following Realtime Database structure

[image: DB Structure]

Now I want to query the aeds by their owner so that the query returns all aeds (with children) with the matching owner id.

But somehow I am not capable to do it although I feel it must be easy. Here is the code I have:

```
var aedRef = dbRef.ref().child("aeds")
var query = aedRef.orderByChild("owner").equalTo(userID);
console.log(query);
```

I feel that it should be easy but somehow I can't get it working. All I get is this:

```
e {repo: e, path: e, Me: e, Le: true}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2):

`query` is just a document reference, it is not the result of the query. You need to use `.on` or `.once` on it to get it to return data.

Check the [Firebase docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write) for more info on how to read and write data.

```js
var aedRef = dbRef.ref().child("aeds");
var query = aedRef.orderByChild("owner").equalTo(userID);

// Get data and keep listening for changes
query.on('value', function(snapshot) {
  console.log(snapshot.val());
});

// Only get data once
query.once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
  console.log(snapshot.val());
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much!